# How to temporarily exclude files from being built

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perforce

My project files are controlled by Perforce and I have installed the SCC plugin so that I can work directly with Perforce inside Visual Studio 2010.

Here is the problem I have:

Inside the project, there are several files that I don't want to take into consideration while I build the project. If I use the context menu "Exclude from Project", I saw the following warning message:

> Checked out items cannot be deleted by your source control provider.
>   If you continue with the change, you may need to manually delete
>   xxx.‌h in the source control database.

Is there a workaround that I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply do not want them to compile, select the code file and look at the Properties window.  Set **Build Action** to content or some other non-compile setting.